# How to get Data from Nested Array [Laravel]

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

To the point, so in this question I want to embed Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking that has been needed for my company, in this case I have an array which is here

```
data_diri": [

{

    "nama_pasien": "ahmad karim harahap",
    "email_pasien": null,
    "birth_date": "3",
    "birth_month": "06",
    "birth_year": "1965",
    "gender": "1",
    "alamat": "jalan jakarta",
    "cit_code": "0",
    "telp": "0211111",
    "layanan": "1",
    "home_service_date": "25",
    "home_service_month": "05",
    "home_service_year": "2016"

}
```

Sorry if there is an error with my json files but it was a valid json, so my question is how can I get the value of the child of "data_diri" value...

I am using return command from php e.g.

```
return $result;
```

and to get "data_diri" I use:

```
return $result[0]["data_diri"];
```

so how can I get the nested value of "data_diri"?
I am using

```
return $result[0]["data_diri"]["nama_pasien"];
```

but it doesn't return anything but error "undefined index: nama_pasien", is there any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: $data =  json_decode($result[0]["data_diri"]);   return ["nama_pasien"] ;    or use toaary() end of query

Comment: @ehsan it returns an error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data_diri` is an array with items, so you need to run:

```
return $result[0]["data_diri"][0]["nama_pasien"];
```

This will return the first item in `data_diri`.

If there are more results in the `data_diri` you need to add a foreach loop if you don't want the first value.

Hope this works and choose the method you want to use!

---

**Your next question**

You can loop through the results like this:

First you need to return the results

```
return $result;
```

After that you can loop through all the data like this:

```
$data = new GoogleAnalytics(); //this is a controller
$result = $data->getData; //this is a method in the GoogleAnalytics Controller
foreach($results as $result) {
    dump($result); //this will dump the array
    foreach($result['data_diri'] as $data) {
        dump($data['nama_pasien']);
    }
}
```

This will dump all `nama_pasien` in the `data_diri` array.

Hope this works!

Comment: Great, after this maybe I need to do looping for get the other value... do you have any example for getting all the same value in different array? (I hope you understand with my question)

Comment: @YukoPangestu look my post, I added another method. Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you so much, I will use getData then for the other thing... I have hard time to find exact tutorial how to code google analytics in laravel...

Comment: @YukoPangestu if you have any questions, you can contact me at all time (visit my profile for more information)

Comment: Thank you very much, nice to meet you sir